# Почему erlang не использует параллельность в обработчиках списков?

Tags: erlang, распараллеливание

Следующий код из учебника Erlang от Армстронга:

```
pythag(N) ->
    [ {A,B,C} ||
        A <- lists:seq(1,N),
        B <- lists:seq(1,N),
        C <- lists:seq(1,N),
        A + B + C =< N,
        A * A + B * B =:= C * C
    ].
```

При вызове pythag(N), erlang использует на 100% только одно ядро из 4 доступных при очевидной возможности распараллеливания (особенно необходимого при N>100). Так и должно быть? Как сделать, чтобы данный пример обрабатывался параллельно?

Answer (score 1):

Не выполняется это параллельно из-за отсутствия разделяемой памяти между процессами т.е. только один процесс может "съедать" голову списка, у другого процесса будет свой список. Это можно было бы решить прореживанием списков или пометкой, что все функции в этой цепочке чистые. Механизма "чистых" функций в эрланге нет, а параллельно обработать прореженные списки - спавни новые процессы, только так.